# undefined method `where' for [2, 7, 15, 16]:Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I want exclude some id that I have detarminated using this code.
I used Ancestry gem that provides with posibility to categorize each category in multiple levels.

```
@sub_ids = @category.child_ids #returns child ids for category           
@extracted_2= @sub_ids.select.with_index{|_,i| (i+1) % 3 == 0} #extracts each third id from array
```

Then using ths code I want to from  root id collection exclude these ID's that I have determinated to be each third.

```
 @subcat = Category.where('id NOT in (?)', @extracted_2) #NOT WORKING
```

I got such error :

**undefined method `where' for [2, 7, 15, 16]:Array**

I believe it is because array dont have such thing ID's to determinate their position in it.
So then how it can work out?

**My point in two words is like :** I want to separate main array into two different arrays.

1. 1st consists from ID's that I believe are each third from main array
2. 2nd array consists from ID's that are from main array but without any ID's from first array.

Full code of controller action :

```
 @params = params[:category]

    @title= "SIA Ecotechno - Products"
    scope = if params[:manufacturer_id]
        Manufacturer.find_by_name(params[:manufacturer_id])
  else
     Manufacturer
  end

       if params[:category].present?
          @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])           
          @sub_ids = @category.child_ids #atgriež visus child ids            
          @extracted_2= @sub_ids.select.with_index{|_,i| (i+1) % 3 == 0}  
          @sub_ids_left = @sub_ids.where('NOT in (?)',@extracted_2)    
          @subcat = Category.find('id NOT in (?)', @extracted_2)

       end


    @manufacturer_products = Product.where(:name=>@manu)

    @prods = Product.where("category_id = ?", @category).paginate(:per_page=>6, :page=> params[:page])w        
 if @category.blank?
 else
      @path = @category.path 
 end

    @first = Category.find(1)
    @root = @first.siblings
    @children1 = @first.children
    @second = Category.find(17)
    @children2 = @second.children
    @third = Category.find(33)
    @children3 = @third.children    
      respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.json { render json: @products }
    end
```

Full trace :

```
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:39:in `index'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__389026677__process_action__502411758__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__720771256__call__1059896576__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:82:in `block in pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `catch'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `pre_process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:55:in `process'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:41:in `receive_data'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
eventmachine-1.0.3-x86 (mingw32) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
thin (1.6.1) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace? I don't believe the error lies in the last line you've pasted. Also the full code of the controller action would help.

Comment: The problem is in this line: `@sub_ids_left = @sub_ids.where('NOT in (?)',@extracted_2)`. `@sub_ids_left` is an array and arrays don't have an instance method called `where`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line (line 14):

```
@sub_ids_left = @sub_ids.where('NOT in (?)',@extracted_2)
```

with this:

```
@sub_ids_left = @sub_ids - @extracted_2
```